# Removing disabled attribute from outer span on an checkbox list control

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

For an asp.net CheckBoxList control,

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="chklStat" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" Enabled="false" />
```

Renders ,

```
<span id="C_chklStat" disabled="disabled">
 <span>
   <input id="C_chklStat_0" type="checkbox" name="M$C$chklStat$0" disabled="disabled" value="1" /><label for="C_chklStat_0">Installed</label>
 </span>
</span>
```

Is there an easy way to remove the disabled attribute from the outer span, C_chklStat?

Comment: I am just curious why having the span disabled matters for your application?

Comment: Just readability, at least in IE, the text is grayed out which makes it harder to read. It didn't occur to me to change this with javascript when the page loaded.

Comment: If the checkbox is disabled (grayed out), to me it makes sense for the label to appear grayed out as well.  It gives a clear message to the user that "you can't do anything with this checkbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CheckBoxList assumes dynamic ids while rendering, the only value you can be sure of is "Installed". Select with that

```
$('label:contains("Installed")').parent().parent().removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I was hoping to find something server side. This is jquery correct? Although this isn't a bad alternative. Thanks.